# Rollup field in Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

Is there a way to force a rollup field to do it's calculation rather than having to "refresh" the field on the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CalculateRollupFieldRequest` in plugin when component field is updated:

```cs
CalculateRollupFieldRequest request= new CalculateRollupFieldRequest
{
    Target = new EntityReference("<entityname>", recordId),
    FieldName = "<rollup field to refresh>"
};

CalculateRollupFieldResponse response = (CalculateRollupFieldResponse)service.Execute(request);
```